# Alternative for pylibmc cache backend in django 1.7

Tags: python, django, memcached, pylibmc

I have recently migrated from django 1.6 to 1.7 which has the following changes:

> If you instantiate cache backends directly, be aware that they aren’t thread-safe any more, as django.core.cache.caches now yields different instances per thread.

Since I use uwsgi in production with threads, I've started getting errors from pylibmc (which is not thread-safe).

I want to ask if there is any substitution for pylibmc backend. I know there is another backend served with django (python-memcached), but i've read that it is not suitable for highload solutions since it's quite slower than pylibmc.

Comment: already has solution yet? I realy need a solution for this problem..

Comment: @SancaKembang We chose django-pylibmc (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pylibmc) as a backend. Seems to be ok now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is thread-safe alternative of `pylibmc`, you could try the gist https://gist.github.com/mrts/334682

Comment: This patch was created 7 years ago and needs to be fixed for current version of django